# how can i <input type="text" onchange sql query?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo

i have a table and when i select some cell, there is another table that i want to make an sql code to change it. how can i associate this two table? i tried to get the value of first table with javascript;

```
 var data = document.getElementById('somevalue').value;
```

but how can i send this value to php to make an PDO query? i tried this codes that i found here but i couldnt understand..

```
<script>
            getName(){
            var data = document.getElementById('somevalue').value;
             $.post("page.php",function(data){

             alert(data);
             });
             }
            </script>
            <?php
                function phpfunction() {
                    echo $data;
               }
              phpfunction();
```

when i run this phpmyadmin gave an error that  `Notice: Undefined variable: data in...`

Thanks for your helps...

Comment: I don't get what you are asking @Hüseyin

Comment: Please find a tutorial on how to send data from a web page to PHP and how to handle databases. This is way too broad to handle here.

Comment: There is no SQL involved in your code, and nothing to be run in phpMyAdmin..... can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sending the data to php with your ajax request.

```
$.post("page.php",function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

should be :

```
$.post("page.php",{ data: data }, function(response){
    alert(reponse);
});
```

where `data: data` means `{ nameOfTheParameterToSend : actualValue }`

(I changed the name of the argument to `response` to stop confusion)